# Template for many composite components on one page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hello i want to make some composite component for finding some documents on my web app. I am trying to make some browser template and reuse this component with many places. It should be hided at load and u can show/hide it by link "browser". Its not so hard till i want to use 2 browser on 1 page, the javascript and cookies ale nor prepared for that, some solutions?

code:

composite component of browser(can i use template in other way than decorater?):

```
<ui:component ... />
    <composite:implementation>
        <ui:decorate template="/WEB-INF/templates/browserTemplate.xhtml">
              <ui:define name="fields">...here fields for browser etc...</ui:define>
        </ui:decorate>
    </ui:component>
</ui:component>
```

template:

```
<ui:composition ...>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".browserAdvenced").click(function() {
                if ($.cookie('browserShowed') === "1") {
                $("#browserPanel").slideUp();
                $.cookie('browserShowed', '0');
            } else {
                $("#browserPanel").slideDown();
                $.cookie('browserShowed', '1');
            }
        });
    </script>
   <h:form id="browserForm">
        <div id="browserPanel" class="content-wide padding">
            <ui:insert name="fields"/>
            <a href="#" class="browserAdvenced"
                title="show/hide browser">find</a>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition ...>
```